# Bounce settings not connecting to iredmail server with correct authentication details

Tags: email, postfix, mail, dovecot

I am using a VPS Server, Abuntu 22.04, PHP 7.3 and Interspire Email Marketer (IEM).

The errors below occurs when I set the bounce email (in IEM) the same as it was previously on another VPS server.

When I set the bounce server smtp user, password etc (correctly) then click TEST BOUNCE SETTINGS, I get the following popup error.

Connection Timed Out
Verify your server is not firewalled
Try using a different protocol or port combination

I have of course turned firewalls off on both servers to test. And different combinations of protocols (imap and pop3 (pop3 is recommended).

The server mail.log shows the following issues when I click the TEST BOUNCE SETTINGS button.

PLEASE NOTE: XXX is IEM server/client (source) IP, and YYY is Mail Server IP. (I have also stripped the dates, times and sessions).

```
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Aborted login by logging out (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Aborted login by logging out (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Too many invalid commands (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Too many invalid commands (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Too many invalid commands (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Too many invalid commands (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, session=
mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX, lip=YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=
```

However, If I use another bounce email address on my shared hosting account the bounce tests okay. But I want to be able to use the YYY server as the bounce email/server.

The Bounce server has iRedMail, postfix, dovecot installed.

So from the above it's clear that the MailServer is the issue and not the IEM client side. And, all functions as far as I can see are working fine, apart from this bounce email connection.

I also have Fail2Ban installed and have allowed the XXX IEM client so its not banning the IP address of IEM.

Thanks in advance.

**IN ADDITION**: If I use the shared hosting bounce email, it processes the bounces, but I get another error when registering through IEM. The error is described here under: **Recipient address rejected: Sender is not same as SMTP authenticate username:** I have tried both those solutiuons but they too dont solve the issue.

https://docs.iredmail.org/errors.html#recipient-address-rejected-sender-is-not-same-as-smtp-authenticate-username

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. It was the `SSL=Required` in `dovedot.conf` file. Changed it to `SSL=Yes` and the bounce email connects now. Not sure of the implications of that but its working. So I can move onto the another underlying issue of autoresponders and form emails not being sent. Hopefully it was for the same reason? TBD